# How to log pastable DDL with HibernateJpaVendorAdapter

Tags: hibernate, logging, spring-data-jpa, hbm2ddl

In a former project I used the `hbm2ddl` task in `hibernate3-maven-plugin` to generate the DDL code - I ran the maven task with debug output enabled and the DDL was logged to the console in a pastable fashion. In fact I used this code as the initial migration for the deployment. Configuration was like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
  <hibernatetool>
    <annotationconfiguration
      configurationfile="src/main/resources/db/database/config/annotatedhibernate.cfg.xml"
      propertyfile="src/main/resources/db/database/config/hibernate.properties" />
    <hbm2ddl drop="true" create="true" delimiter=";" format="true" console="true" outputfilename="output.ddl" />
  </hibernatetool>
</configuration>
```

Nowadays I discovered the beauty of `spring-data-jpa` and configured the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` to generate my DDL code. Soon I wish to deploy and like to log the pastable DDL code to the console (or somewhere) but I only figured out how to setup and configure the hibernate logging and am able to set log levels and stuff - but the beauty DDLs like in the maven debug never show up. How can I enable this using the HibernateJpaVendorAdapter. Current configuration below:

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
  <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
  <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.recipes.api.impl" />
</bean>
```